# Did I correctly spot a cameo in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, cameo

I saw TFA twice over the weekend and the second time through, I spotted an older guy that looked and sounded an awful lot like

> Temuera Morrison with a bunch of movie make-up to make him look really old.

He appeared for a second during the assault on Starkiller Base as a Resistance officer in the room with Leia. I can't remember his exact quote but he makes some quick observational statement about the battle to Leia. Was this

> Temuera Morrison appearing as a ridiculously old clone?

I didn't see him in the credits and I can't find anything online about it so I'm thinking I might be crazy... Plus the scene went by too fast to truly get a solid look.

Comment: I thought this question would be about Daniel Craig... Can't help you with this guy, sadly.

Comment: The first batch of clones were (physically) aged about 25 in Episode II, which would make them about 75 in Episode VII. Does that really count as "ridiculously old"?

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - My understanding was that they were altered to age much faster than a normal person. So 50 years may have passed since the Clone Wars but it's likely a lot more than that in clone years. My intention wasn't to call 75 ancient or anything. :)

Comment: Did you mean this guy? http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/star-wars-canon/images/4/43/Jenkins.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20151124042306

Comment: No, I saw that guy earlier in the movie. The one I'm looking for was seated at a terminal kind of like this except facing right rather than left: http://img.lum.dolimg.com/v1/images/open-uri20150608-27674-1wei3uk_c4a86c20.jpeg?region=0%2C0%2C1280%2C720

Comment: @sam as its 50 years since the clonwars that would be +100 years in clone trooper years...add their prior aging and you are WAY above 120 years

Comment: Kaminoan clones were bred from 32-19 BBY, and they aged at twice the rate of normal humans. Ep VII occurred at 33-34 ABY. The youngest clone would by now be 52 human age and 104 clone age, the youngest veteran 124. Even with galactic medical standards, someone still combat fit at that age is unlikely to be present.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - True. If he was on the battlefield I would've assumed I was just seeing things. But he was only sitting in the war room manning some tech. I'm probably wrong about what I saw but I'd love to know who it really was.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this guy?

[image]

Major Ematt had one line and was played by Andrew Jack

Comment: I don't think so... It's been a month since I've last seen the flick and I'm having a little trouble remembering exactly what I saw. It was literally a split second thing. This may be one of those things I'll have to wait to get an answer for until after I pick up the blu-ray.